# Intercept and retry call by means of OkHttp Interceptors

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I need to retry request inside of `OkHttp Interceptor`. For example there is incoming request which needs `Authorization` token. If `Authorization` token is expired, server returns response with `403` code. In this case I am retrieving a new token and trying to make call again by using the same `chain` object.

But OkHttp throws an exception, which states that you cannot make two requests with the same `chain` object.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: network interceptor org.app.api.modules.ApplicationApiHeaders@559da2 must call proceed() exactly once
```

I wonder if there is a clean solution to this problem of retrying network request inside of `OkHttp Interceptor`?

```java
public final class ApplicationApiHeaders implements Interceptor {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private TokenProvider mProvider;

    public ApplicationApiHeaders(TokenProvider provider) {
        mProvider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Token token = mProvider.getApplicationToken();
        String bearerToken = "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken();

        System.out.println("Token: " + bearerToken);
        Request request = chain.request();
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, bearerToken)
                .build();

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (!response.isSuccessful() && isForbidden(response.code())) {
            Token freshToken = mProvider.invalidateAppTokenAndGetNew();
            String freshBearerToken = freshToken.getAccessToken();

            Request newRequest = chain.request();
            newRequest = newRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, freshBearerToken)
                    .build();

            response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static boolean isForbidden(int code) {
        return code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `.interceptors()` instead of `.networkInterceptors()` which are allowed to call `.proceed()` more than once.

For more information see: https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Comment: Link is unavailable.