# How to set a delay for interceptor in okhttp?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Lets say we need to retry a request in case of exception:

```
public class TestUpInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        //TODO: in case of exception retry in 3 sec
        return retryResponse;
    }
}
```

how to add a delay to interceptor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536522/intercept-and-retry-call-by-means-of-okhttp-interceptors

Comment: Do you really want to repeat your request or you just worry that it might fail in case of patchy Internet ? [Coz you dont really need to worry about the latter](https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace)

Comment: @ZeekHuge I'd like to repeat